# Displaying Data after reading from text file - C#,Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textfield

I have a text file with data which might look something like:

> UserName
>
> Address
>
> PostCode
>
> PhoneNumber

The first four elements of the textfile belongs to one user, the next four to next user etc. I want to read from a textfile, and display data of each user. Reading and distinguishing data of each user is fine.
  The problem is how would I display the data as such? I would like to display the data as a table or something along the line, where each user has a row. Say I want to display data like;

> Name - Address - Postcode - PhoneNumber
>
> Matt -  15 The -  PO30 78 -  088997655
>
> Mike -  16 The -  PO31 78 -  088998955

If I was using a database I guess you can easily display it with a GridView, is there anyway to display it after reading from textfile?

Many Thanks,
Mike

EDIT:
I copied the code you gave, dragged a gridView to the page. Changed it's ID to dataGridView1

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
   table.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("PostCode", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    table.Rows.Add(Label8.Text, Label4.Text, Label5.Text, Label6.Text, Label7.Text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your data into a DataTable and bind a gridview to the DataTable just as you would if it were coming from from a database. Something like this:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Postcode", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("PhoneNumber", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add("Matt", "15 The", "PO30 78", "088997655");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks. So I just drag a GridView(with id=dataGridView1) into the page, and do this? I tried this and for some reason my gridview does not show up. I assume it is because there is no data to show. So I guess it didn't add anything to gridview. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @user1005253 Yes, you will have to post the code you are trying, because if I use what is posted in my answer, it works as expected (I tested it first)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my original post to display the code.

Comment: Did a bit of looking around. Added `dataGridView1.DataBind();` Now it works. cheers :)

Comment: @user1005253 I have updated my answer. I am actually surprised this worked without it now that you say that.